# IPython notebook webpages taking long time to load

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

The ipython server on my computer was working fine but 
it lately it takes a long time (> 15 mins) to load the home  page `(localhost:port/tree)` and is not formatted properly. Wget returns the homepage immediately but has formatting issues too.
Could it be a css issue?

**Things I have tried, though without success:**
 1. Modifying the html (commenting out some of the css includes) which
    are present in the packages directory. 
 2. Reinstalling the `ipython` and `jupyter` packages.

I am using Enthought Canopy for my python packages.
The ipython version is 4.1.2 and jupyter 4.1.0. I used 
pip to install the packages.

Thanks

N.B: Sorry, I don't have the reputation to post the screenshot
of the incorrectly formatted homepage.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's Javascript console when that happens? What do you get from `import mimetypes; mimetypes.guess_type('foo.css')`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem seems to be with  style.min.css.  The console once gave a message saying there was error loading style.min.css.  Running mimetypes.guess_type('foo.css') returns ('text/css', None). There are two style.min.css in my system: one in /usr/share/ipython and another in /usr/local/lib (this is used by the server). I copied the css file from the other location. Now it loads immediately but the formatting is odd. For example the buttons are very big.   Thanks

Comment: The one in `/usr/share/system` was probably for an older version of the notebook, so it won't match up correctly to the structure of the page now. I'm not sure why that file would have made the page take so long to load.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The latest style.min.css (in /usr/local/lib) is making the loading of page slow. I tried validating the css using a online validator, but strangely both the css give error. I have tried canopy and anaconda distribution without any luck. The easiest way seems to be replace with new style.min.css but latest version in github has .less files for css.Thanks.

Comment: The less files are compiled to CSS when we do a release. You could try updating notebook to 4.2.0, which was recently released.

Comment: The issue was with iptables rules on my machine. I flushed the rules and now it is working fine.